# Why does this error stop the rendering of my react app?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I keep getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'children' of '_ref' as it is undefined.

I know it has to do with the children params I added in the context but I don't know how to fix it or why my app doesn't render and components because of it. This is my code:

**Header.js:**

```
 import * as React from 'react';
import './Header.css'
import CryptoState from '../CryptoContext'
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, Container, Select, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {

  const { currency, setCurrency } = CryptoState() 
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      main: '#00CADF',
    },
  });
return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
  <AppBar color='transparent' position='static'>
    <Container>
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant='h6' onClick = {() => navigate('/')}id='name'>Crypto Tracker</Typography>
        <Select color = 'primary' id='currency' style={{
          width: 100,
          height: 35,
          marginRight: 15,
        }}
        value={currency}
        onChange={(event) => setCurrency(event.target.value)}
        >
          <MenuItem value={'USD'}>USD</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={'CAD'}>CAD</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </Toolbar>
    </Container>
  </AppBar>
  </ThemeProvider>
)

}

export default Header;
```

**CryptoContext.js**

```
    import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


const Crypto = createContext('')
const CryptoContext = ({children}) => {
    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("USD")
    const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("$")
    useEffect(() => {
      if (currency === 'USD') setSymbol("$");
      else if (currency === 'CAD') setSymbol("c")
    }, [currency])
  return (
    <Crypto.Provider value={{currency, setCurrency}}>{children}</Crypto.Provider>
  )
}

export default CryptoContext

export const CryptoState = () => {
    return useContext(Crypto)
}
```

**Index.js:**

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import CryptoContext from './CryptoContext';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CryptoContext>
    <App />
    </CryptoContext>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

```
    import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Homepage from './Pages/Homepage';
import CoinPage from './Pages/CoinPage';


function App() {
  return (
<BrowserRouter>
    <div >
      <Header />
      <Routes>
<Route exact path='/' element={<Homepage />} />
<Route path='/coins/:id' element={<CoinPage />} />
</Routes>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Try by move ThemeProvider to index.js ,    And Add Full errors , you are getting

Comment: Can you post your `App.js` component?

Comment: Sure, I just updated it

Comment: this is a great candidate for a demo on codesandbox.io - you'd get feedback much faster if you have a working demo

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your default export from CryptoContext, you're exporting the Provider and then in your component you're trying to consume it as a hook

```js
// CryptoContext.js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


const Crypto = createContext('')
const CryptoContext = ({children}) => {
    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("USD")
    const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("$")
    useEffect(() => {
      if (currency === 'USD') setSymbol("$");
      else if (currency === 'CAD') setSymbol("c")
    }, [currency])
  return (
    <Crypto.Provider value={{currency, setCurrency}}>{children}</Crypto.Provider>
  )
}

export default CryptoContext

// As React suggest naming for hooks , [use]
export const useCryptoState = () => {
    return useContext(Crypto)
}
```

Then you do this at Header.js

```js
// Header.js
import * as React from 'react';
import './Header.css'
import { useCryptoState } from '../CryptoContext'
// Error was here, named export not the default export 
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, Container, Select, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {

  const { currency, setCurrency } = useCryptoState() 
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      main: '#00CADF',
    },
  });
return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
  <AppBar color='transparent' position='static'>
    <Container>
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant='h6' onClick = {() => navigate('/')}id='name'>Crypto Tracker</Typography>
        <Select color = 'primary' id='currency' style={{
          width: 100,
          height: 35,
          marginRight: 15,
        }}
        value={currency}
        onChange={(event) => setCurrency(event.target.value)}
        >
          <MenuItem value={'USD'}>USD</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={'CAD'}>CAD</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </Toolbar>
    </Container>
  </AppBar>
  </ThemeProvider>
)

}

export default Header;
```